# Docker for Windows fails to pull private image. Error is "context cancelled"

Tags: windows, docker

I'm on a Windows 10 system using Docker for Windows to manage Linux Docker containers. I can successfully pull and run the `hello-world` image so there's no issues with pulling and running images from the public Docker hub.

However, I have an executable (`.exe`) that pulls and runs private Docker images hosted in AWS ECR amongst other things. The application does all the necessary work to prepare the credentials to authorize the pull but when it goes to pull it shows the typical `pulling fs layers` and `waiting` stdout. After about 5-10 of each it outputs `context cancelled` and kills the application.

Any ideas?